# How to pass a ng-model to a function in ng-click without $scope

Tags: angularjs

I saw a lot of responses to this but all use `$scope`

I have several `ng-models` with a couple of buttons to increase or decrease the value, I would like to use just one function for all.

Like this:

```js
app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller("myCtrl", mainFunction);

function mainFunction(){
  scope = this;
  this.value1 = 3;
  this.value2 = 5;
  this.addOne = function (control) {
        if (scope.control <12){
            scope.control += 1;
        }
    }

    this.dimOne = function (control) {
        if (scope.control > 1) {
            scope.control -= 1;
        }
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">

   <span>{{vm.value1}}</span>
   <button ng-click="vm.dimOne('value1')">-</button>
   <button ng-click="vm.addOne('value1')">+</button>
   <br />
   <span>{{vm.value2}}</span>
   <button ng-click="vm.dimOne('value2')">-</button>
   <button ng-click="vm.addOne('value2')">+</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you could change the inner html of the span ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to be passing the string of what you want, just update your functions:

```
this.addOne = function (control) {
    if (scope[control] < 12) {
        scope[control] += 1;
    }
}

this.dimOne = function (control) {
    if (scope[control] > 1) {
        scope[control] -= 1;
    }
}
```

Also... is your html supposed to be this?

```
<span>{{vm.value1}}</span>
<button ng-click="vm.dimOne('value1')">-</button>
<button ng-click="vm.addOne('value1')">+</button>
<br />
<span>{{vm.value2}}</span>
<button ng-click="vm.dimOne('value2')">-</button>
<button ng-click="vm.addOne('value2')">+</button>
```

Comment: Yes, there was an error in HTML, I had fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just pass the actual `model` :-

```
<button ng-click="vm.dimOne(vm.value2)">-</button>
```

`*.js`

```
this.dimOne = function (control) {
    if (control > 1) {
        control -= 1;
        this.value2 = control ;
    }
}
```

Comment: you're right there a separate method  for that with needed functionality